# How to fit image in irregular shape frame

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I have a problem regarding irregular shape. I searched a lot but nothing was useful for me. I have a number of frames of irregular shape and each frame is again divided into sub areas. I want to fit images from photo library in each sub areas of frame. But i am unable to get location of each sub areas and since shape is also irregular so again another problem to fit image in that area. Can anyone help me !! This is an example of that frame.[image: Image Having two odd shape frame]

Comment: Can you give us a little info about the nature of the shape and how it is generated, the nature of the "sub areas", etc.?

Comment: Think that there is circle and it is divided into four parts. I have to add images in that area. The boundary of circle and line dividing it into for parts will be part of frame and all other part of frame will be transparent means, i have to fit imageview on that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can never have irregular shaped frames. Frames will always in rect shape. 
You can have it done by detecting transparent areas.

[Refer this link. It will give you idea how to do that :)](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html)

Comment: I think I misunderstood your Question :| Can you explain the exact scenario?

Comment: Think that there is circle and it is divided into four parts. I have to add images in that area. The boundary of circle and line dividing it into for parts will be part of frame and all other part of frame will be transparent means, i have to fit imageview on that part.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to clip the various images by the arc of the circle? For example, here is a screen snapshot with four images (just random images I got from a search for dogs on http://images.google.com):

[image: uncropped]

And here are the same four images cropped by a circle (or more accurately, each of the four images were separately cropped by the same circle path):

[image: cropped]

Here is the code that does that

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)image locatedAt:(CGRect)imageFrame byCircleAt:(CGPoint)center withRadius:(float)radius
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, imageFrame.size.width, imageFrame.size.height, 8, 4 * imageFrame.size.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGRect ellipseFrame = CGRectMake(center.x - imageFrame.origin.x - radius, imageFrame.size.height - (center.y - imageFrame.origin.y - radius) - radius * 2.0, radius * 2.0, radius * 2.0);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, ellipseFrame);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageFrame.size.width, imageFrame.size.height), image.CGImage);

    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];

    CGImageRelease(imageMasked);

    return newImage;
}

- (void)addSingleCroppedImage:(UIImage *)image at:(CGRect)imageFrame byCircleAt:(CGPoint)center withRadius:(float)radius
{
    UIImage *newImage = [self cropImage:image locatedAt:imageFrame byCircleAt:center withRadius:radius];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
    imageView.image = newImage;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

- (void)addCroppedImages
{
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0);
    float radius = 150.0;

    UIImage *dog1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imgres-1.jpg"]];
    UIImage *dog2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imgres-2.jpg"]];
    UIImage *dog3 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imgres-3.jpg"]];
    UIImage *dog4 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imgres-4.jpg"]];

    CGRect frame;
    UIImage *currentImage;

    // upper left

    currentImage = dog1;
    frame = CGRectMake(center.x - currentImage.size.width, center.y - currentImage.size.height, currentImage.size.width, currentImage.size.height);
    [self addSingleCroppedImage:currentImage at:frame byCircleAt:center withRadius:radius];

    // upper right

    currentImage = dog2;
    frame = CGRectMake(center.x, center.y - currentImage.size.height, currentImage.size.width, currentImage.size.height);
    [self addSingleCroppedImage:currentImage at:frame byCircleAt:center withRadius:radius];

    // lower left

    currentImage = dog3;
    frame = CGRectMake(center.x - currentImage.size.width, center.y, currentImage.size.width, currentImage.size.height);
    [self addSingleCroppedImage:currentImage at:frame byCircleAt:center withRadius:radius];

    // lower right

    currentImage = dog4;
    frame = CGRectMake(center.x, center.y, currentImage.size.width, currentImage.size.height);
    [self addSingleCroppedImage:currentImage at:frame byCircleAt:center withRadius:radius];
}
```

Comment: ya dear you got my point. But you are cropping image after setting image in four image view, but my problem is that i have a frame like in your second image and i have to set image in this frame. Means my frame is defined already and i have to set image on touch in that particular area.

Comment: So you have simply one image that you want to crop with a circle? Or you have an existing graphical element for a circular "frame" (that's a bad word because it means something very different in the UIView world!) that you need to put your image(s) into? Not sure if I understand what sort of thing this "frame" you refer to is.